# Optimising mysql query - many inner joins

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to optimise the following query in wordpress, as it takes nearly a minute and a half to return a result. The table relationships are expressed in the following diagram:

[image]

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts . *
    FROM wp_posts
       INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
        ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
       INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt1 
        ON (wp_posts.ID = tt1.object_id)
       INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt2 
        ON (wp_posts.ID = tt2.object_id)
       INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt3 
        ON (wp_posts.ID = tt3.object_id)
       INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt4 
        ON (wp_posts.ID = tt4.object_id)
    WHERE 1 = 1
        AND (
            wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (25) 
            OR tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (26) 
            OR tt2.term_taxonomy_id IN (16) 
            OR tt3.term_taxonomy_id IN (17) 
            OR tt4.term_taxonomy_id IN (18)
        ) 
        AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('product') 
        AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
    GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
    ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC
    LIMIT 0 , 15
```

Comment: I am having difficulties to understand what you are trying to achieve here. Maybe you could provide us with a clear-text explaination of the most important entities and the result you are trying to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the point of all the inner joins on the wp_term_relationships table when all it appears you're doing is looking for a series of values. Wouldn't the following perform the same and execute much faster?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts . *
    FROM wp_posts
       INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
        ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (25, 26, 16, 17, 18) 
        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' 
        AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
    GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
    ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC
    LIMIT 0 , 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think this will be faster.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts . *
FROM wp_posts,
     wp_term_relationships 
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (25,26,16,17,18)
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' 
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC
LIMIT 0 , 15
```

You do not need so many INNER JOINS.

Answer (score 0):

If the idea behind the multiple joins was to retrieve the posts with a corresponding `term_taxonomy_id` of 25 and also 26 and also 17,... (meaning **ALL of the terms** as opposed to ANY of them), you can reuse KayakJim's answer with only one JOIN and add an `HAVING` clause, keeping only the rows that matched with all of the 5 terms.

Here would be the modified query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts . *
    FROM wp_posts
       INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
        ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (25, 26, 16, 17, 18) 
        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' 
        AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
    GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
    HAVING count(*)=5
    ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC
    LIMIT 0 , 15
```